# Refactor service with too many dependencies

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm developing a Web Application with `Spring Framework`(`Spring Boot`) and `JDBC` (no `JPA` or `ORM`) so I'm using `Dependency Injection` to use `Beans` through layers. The structure is composed by three main layers: DB (DAOs), Service and Controller. `DAOs` are injected in other `DAOs` or in `Service layer` and `Services` in other `Services` and in `Controller Layer`.

My `Database layer` is composed by one `DAO` for each the tables of the database. Each `DAO`has the general `CRUD`and some specific operations according to its needs. In total I have more than 10 tables (nearly 15 maybe).

Example of DAO

```
public class Dao1 implements Crud<Entity, Integer>{


     public Entity findById(Integer id){
          //Impl Jdbc
     }


     public void insert(Entity entity){
          //JDbc impl
     }


    //Other CRUD operations -> Update, delete,...

}
```

In the `Service layer` I map `Entities` (Database objects) to `DTos`(Data access object).

### Problem

I have a `@Service` class with It is needed to inject too much dependencies (10 dependencies) of data access object.

Why? I've got a complex `DTO` class which is needed to fill getting some data of each `entity` (using `DAOs`) and doing some operations also (`Update`, `insert`, `delete.`....

Example of Service

```
public class ServiceO{

   @Autowired
   private Dao1 dao1;
   @Autowired
   private Dao2 dao2;
   //assume there are 10 daos....

   public ObjectComplexDTO findObject(int id){

     ObjectComplexDTO dto = mapToObjectComplexDTO(dao1.findById(id));
     dto.setOtherObjects(mapToOtherObjectDto(dao2.findByCompleDto(id)));
     // and so on....

     return dto;

  }
}
```

When I reviewed my `@Service` I saw clearly it`s needed to refactor this class but I'm not sure how.

I have considered the following options:

- Create a `Class` which groups by functionality: but extract data remain too much, 7 dependencies...
- Group `DAOs` (no just one `DAO` for `Entity`) and Make more complex `SQL` and extract more data giving more functionality to the `Database Engine` in the `Entities` of this data that only `DTOs` has and then filled in `DAOs` layer: the problem is moved to the layer `DAO`...
- Keep the class knowing that it has too many dependencies.

Do you have any idea's to improve this issue?

Comment: please show your code, if you want advice

Comment: And, maybe when you post more of your code, you could try codereview.stackexchange.com ... but probably this is really more about good DDD ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, I would suggest refactoring your DAOs.  It sounds like you have one DAO per table.  Instead, try to align your DAOs with business requirements in a more Domain-Driven style of design.  Your service layer is required to "know" too much about the data layer and is therefore likely to be unnecessarily coupled to it.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can still have DAOs that perform CRUD operations at the table level, but they don't necessarily need to be exposed outside of the Domain Layer.  You can use them internally to fulfill the external API offered to the Service or UI layers.